# Как распечатать документ docx, odt в Python?

Tags: python, печать, docx

Как распечатать документ docx, odt в Python3. Максимум, что нашел как распечатать txt.

Принтер pos-58 для чеков, система ubuntu 18.04, python3. Есть два файла txt и docx, с первым всё в порядке, а на втором выскакивает ошибка, что-то вроде не поддерживаемый формат. Из Libre печатает. Как на Python3 реализовать?

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать такую библиотеку pycups https://pypi.org/project/pycups/

Comment: Ребята,  напишу подробнее. Принтер pos-58 для чеков, система ubuntu 18.04, python3. Есть два файла txt и docx,  с первым всё в порядке, а на втором выскакивает ошибка, что-то вроде не поддерживаемый формат, точнее напишу вечером. Из Libre печатает. Как на Python3 реализовать?

Comment: Нужна информация как именно печатаете.

Comment: Голосую за закрытие, т.к. вечер 8 октября 2019 г. уже давно прошел, а конкретная ошибка так и не указана.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вызвать Libreофис перегнать файл в pdf или ps которые понимает cups и отдать на печать. Вызови это через subprocess

```
unoconv --stdout filename.doc | lpr -P the_printer_name
```

или

```
libreoffice --pt the_printer_name --headless filename.odt
```

https://superuser.com/a/486150/239779

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте извлечь текст из .docx файла и потом разпечатать его так же как .txt:

```
import docx

def extractText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document('путь_к_файлу')
    text = []
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        text.append(paragraph.text)
    return '\n'.join(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, кому вдруг нужно будет, эта функция отправит документ на печать на основной принтер

```
import win32api
import win32print

def print_doc(filepath, filename):
    f = '"' + filepath + filename + '"'
    win32api.ShellExecute(0, "printto", f, '"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter(), ".", 0)
```

Comment: Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032272/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-docx-odt-%D0%B2-python#comment1757991_1032272): ubuntu 18.04. Функции Windows API под Ubuntu работать не будут.